# W2UI grids : how to get the concerned cell value in render function?

Tags: javascript, w2ui

I need to use cell renderers with a W2UI grid; I do like that :

Renderer function :

```
// Renderer function
let dateRenderer = function(record, index, columnIndex) {
    return `<a href="http://www.example.com/check.php?date=${record.date_start}">${record.date_start}</a>`;
};
```

Columns definition :

```
// ...
// Renderer function call in columns definition
{ field: 'date_start', caption: 'Start date', render: dateRenderer },
// ...
```

It works well, but the problem is that I have a lot of different date columns in my grid and I need to create a different renderer function for each (for exemple whith record.date_start, record.date_end, record.date_shipping, etc...) when all dates in the grid are formated the same way.

Is it possible to get the value of concerned cell in renderer function and no entire record object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following function to get the value of the related cell.

```
this.getCellValue(index, col_index);
```

// index - index of the record 
// col_index - index of the column from the columns list

Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3r8s9o4d/1/) to understand it clearly.

Comment: Thank you RamaKrishna for your help, but take a look at this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/tLpmbr6o/

I need to rewrite the same function twice. How can I use the same render function for either sdate and edate ?

Comment: I tried this : http://jsfiddle.net/9g51jray/ It works well. Thank you !

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, it's an error. This fiddle is the true one :

http://jsfiddle.net/fb8qu7vx/